# CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation not added to exact plot coordinates

Tags: objective-c, annotations, core-plot

I am using Core Plot to plot a bar chart and trying to add an annotation image to the plotSpace by specifying the anchorPlotPoint. The image annotation must be placed exactly on the x-axis at an exact coordinate, however the annotation is offset from the specified coordinate. The offset gets greater as the x coordinate increases.

```
CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation *imageAnnotation;
CPTImage *image = [CPTImage imageWithCGImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dot.png"].CGImage scale:2.0f];
CPTBorderedLayer *imageLayer = [[CPTBorderedLayer alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
imageLayer.fill = [CPTFill fillWithImage:image];
imageAnnotation = [[CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation alloc] initWithPlotSpace:plotSpace anchorPlotPoint:anchorPoint];
imageAnnotation.contentLayer = imageLayer;
[_graph addAnnotation:imageAnnotation];
```

The image being used in this example is a 1 x 1 pixel filled with a colour to see the exactly location it is being plotted. I can plot a Scatterplot onto the same plotSpace using the same anchorPoint coordinates as the annotation which plot correctly. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated as this has stumped me for the last 2 days!

Comment: How far is the point away from where it should be? Annotations are always pixel aligned and there might be a rounding issue with the @2x display.

Comment: The distance between the annotation and the anchor point gets greater the further it moves from away from the axes and at (0,0) the annotation is correctly placed, so yes it seems like a rounding issue. I ran it on the non-retina simulator with scale 1.0 and although the annotation is still offset from the anchor, the distance between them is not as great, or probably half.

Comment: I opened a ticket on the Core Plot [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=505) to track this problem.